# Error to build a signed apk

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

i'm trying to build an signed apk with visual studio /Cordova template. But i'm receiving this error: ERROR building one of the platforms   1

And : Error     MDAVSCLI    1

I´m following this tutorial: 
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/

and my Keystore is like image bellow:

[image]

```
  -package-resources:
   [aapt] Creating full resource package...

  -package:
   [apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced     apkbuilder run.
    [apkbuilder] Creating MainActivity-release-unsigned.apk for release...

 -post-package:

  -release-prompt-for-password:

   -release-nosign:

   -release-sign:
   [echo] Signing final apk...

       BUILD FAILED
      C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\ant\build.xml:1135: The      following error occurred while executing this line:
           C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\ant\build.xml:1147:  C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Mobile\Mobile\platforms\android\"my-release-key.Keystore"   (The file name syntax, the name of the directory or volume label incorrect)

     Total time: 52 seconds
   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Mobile\Mobile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                  throw e;
                        ^
  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant release -f   C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Mobile\Mobile\platforms\android\build.xml -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen"
  Command finished with error code 1:   C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Mobile\Mobile\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --release
  ERROR building one of the platforms : error :  C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Mobile\Mobile\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command   failed with exit code 1
   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
MDAVSCLI : error : C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Mobile\Mooobile\platforms\android\c
```

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using with your VS? For versions 5.0 and higher, you need to use the build.json since the Android build system has moved to Gradle.

Comment: I'm using  version 4.3

Comment: Often the Output window provides more details on errors.  For example, if you are trying to run the app on a device that had the debug version on it previously, the build may be succeeding but you could see an inconsistent certificate error... which just means you need to uninstall the debug version of the app on the device first.  What do you see in the output window?  Also, what version of Tools for Apache Cordova are you using? VS 2015 Update 1/2/3 or VS 2013?

Comment: Visual studio 2015 update 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a  way : removing the quotes in my ant.properties i can build.